# What does an Empty IQueryable return as when Empty?

Tags: c#, null, iqueryable

I am in need of determining whether an IQueryable Method returns with Data, or "Empty" when applying it to a DataSource of a RadGrid like so:

```
RadGrid.DataSource = Method(x);

        if (Method(x) == yyy)
        {
            button.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            button.Enabled = false;
        }
```

I have tried using "null" in place of the "yyy" but with no success. When stepping through the code, the IQueryable Method returns as "Empty" but I am unsure of how to verify that using an If statement.

What does an IQueryable Method return as if it returns as Empty, and how can I verify that using an If Statement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Any() to check to see if there are any elements in the IQueryable:

```
RadGrid.DataSource = Method(x);

if (Method(x).Any())
{
    button.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
    button.Enabled = false;
}
```

(Or, alternatively, the shorter version:)

```
button.Enabled = Method(x).Any();
```

Comment: Are there any extra references I will need to use .Any()? As I am getting errors when trying to compile this.

Comment: @Lando: Typically, if you're using IQueryable already, it should "just work" - it's an extension method on Queryable.Any (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534338.aspx) - Make sure to have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file, as well as a reference to System.Core.dll.

Comment: This is what I had figured also. As I use LINQ on almost all of my current pages, the System.Linq; reference already exists at the top of the page. I am accessing my Methods through a separate .dll I have previously created... that shouldn't make any differences should it?

Comment: @Lando: No - what's the exact error you're seeing?  (Compile time or runtime?  message?)

Comment: The Error is:   Error 95 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) --- Nothing out of the ordinary, but confusing as to why it's not recognizing the Reference.

Comment: @Lando: make sure to reference System.Core.dll

Comment: @Reed: Unfortunately the System.Core.dll is already referenced, therefore there must be an underlying problem affecting my solution. Thanks again for the help, I'm sure this will work once I get .Any() working.

Answer (score 6):

You want to use [`IQueryable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx).

```
bool empty = !queryable.Any();
if(empty) {
    // something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
RadGrid.DataSource = Method(x);            
 if (RadGrid.DataSource as MyObject == null)          
 {              
      button.Enabled = true;          
 }          
 else          
 {              
       button.Enabled = false;          
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
if (Method(x) == Enumerable.Empty<YourType>())
{
    // Your code
}
```

Since `Enumerable.Empty<TResult>()` is cached for `TResult` it will hold the same reference as the empty sequence reterned from `Method` and therefore will be equatable.

If you are unsure whether or not this will work, please run this example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var first = Enumerable.Empty<Example>();
        var second = Enumerable.Empty<Example>();

        Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(first, second));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that's a reference comparison and so fails, in general.

Comment: -1 This will perform a reference comparison.  It should be obvious why this won't work in almost every case.  It will *only* work if the method returns `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` -- and in most cases it will be returning some other enumerable that has no elements.

Comment: Here is my counter-example: `public static IEnumerable<T> Empty<T>() { yield break; } public static bool Test() { return Empty<object>() == Enumerable.Empty<object>(); }`.  `Test()` will return false, as it should.  This will only work if the method being called returns `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` -- not all empty enumerables are equivalent.  Using `Enumerable.Any<T>()` is a much better approach.